# Measuring and documenting internet speed (download and upload)

Tags: internet-connection

I'm looking for a way to document ever couple of minutes the download and upload speed the is supplied to me by the ISP.

There are many tools to show the current upload and download speed (that are being used) but I need to document what the ISP gives me (I suspect that I don't get the speed I pay for during the day).

I guess it would be measured against a specific URL I should supply.

Do you know any tool like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [Tespeed](https://github.com/Janhouse/tespeed). I was going to recommend for example `tcptrack` or `nethogs` but Tespeed is much better as a testing tool.

1. Download from source: `wget https://raw.github.com/Janhouse/tespeed/master/tespeed.py`
2. Give it executable permission: `chmod +x tespeed.py`
3. Execute the file `./tespeed.py`

   [image]

Now if you want to make it run every couple of minutes, you can include that in a cron job as a script or make a small script that you would run anytime you want to start monitoring your ISP. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Time in Seconds
timer="60"
echo "Checking ISP for the TRUTH!!"
while [ $timer -gt 0 ]
do
  echo "Check done at: `date`"  >> timer.log
  ./tespeed.py 2>> timer.log
  sleep $timer
  echo "---------------------" >> timer.log
done
```

Save the above code in some file. For example a file called **timer**. Then give it executable permission like I mentioned above: `chmod +x timer`. Then simply execute the file to start checking you Download and Upload speed every X amount of seconds. The code is for 1 minute right now.

What the code does it run the `tespeed.py` file and output whatever it does to a file called `timer.log`. You can read this file anytime you want. It will show all checks done by `tespeed` since the moment you run the script and it will also show the time when the check was done.

Answer (score 0):

what about [this](http://testmy.net/auto)?

> "This test will give you an accurate log of your connection on a
>   regular interval without having to run back to your computer over and
>   over."

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Can you explain how the OP can log the information obtained from this site?